# How to make a histogram for each row of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

Do I use a for loop? Do I need to use iterrows()?

```
x = df.T[0]
y = df2.T[0]
plt.hist(x, bins=[-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], alpha=0.5, label='x')
plt.hist(y, bins=[-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], alpha=0.5, label='y')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

How do I make df.T[i+1]?

Sample for source data (note I didn't screenshot the column names as they contained sensitive information):
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtYio.png)

I'm trying to do this for every row (this is done with the data from the first row):
[visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWU3K.png)

Comment: Please add a sample of your source data.

Comment: Do you want a separate plot for each row?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a pandas data frame, you can use pandas graphic tools. Check this example:

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data frame creation
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [1, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -2], [2, 0], [-3, -2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [0, -1], [1, 1], [0, 0],
                   [1, 2], [0, 0], [1, -1], [0, -3], [-1, -2], [1, 0], [0, -2]], columns=['column_1', 'column_2'])
num_bins = 5  # Change this number as you need

# Create separate histograms
ax = df.hist(bins=num_bins)

# Create overlapped histograms
ax = df['column_1'].hist(bins=num_bins, label='column_1')
ax = df['column_2'].hist(bins=num_bins, label='column_2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
title_obj = plt.title('Overlapped Histogram', color='dimgrey')
```

Check this link for detailed information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only acceptable solution is to create a histogram
for each row **separately**. First define *bins* in a separate variable:

```
bins=[-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Then, e.g. for row *0* you can run:

```
df.iloc[0].hist(bins=bins);
```

Note the trailing `;` to avoid additional printout (at least in *Jupyter*).

An attempt to superimpose in one picture data from more than 2 rows
will make this picture absolutely unreadable.
And note that you have as many as 107 rows in your DataFrame.

An alternative: To have a number of such pictures in next to each other
(horizontally), e.g. for 5 initial rows, you can run:

```
df.iloc[0:5].T.hist(bins=bins, sharey=True, layout=(1, 5), figsize=(12, 3));
```

The result (for your sample data) is:

[image]

Then repeat the above code for each consecutive set of 5 rows.